# Synchronize REST endpoint to wait for 2 calls with same parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am creating an application in which two players should have an opportunity to compete with each other in writing code.

For example, for now one player can initiate a session creation:

```
@PostMapping("/prepareSession")
    public UUID prepareSession(@RequestParam("taskName") String taskName) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
        User playerOne = userService.findOne(currentPrincipalName);
        Task task = taskService.findOne(taskName);
        UUID sessionId = UUID.randomUUID();
        sessionService.save(new Session(sessionId, playerOne, null, task));
        return sessionId;
    }
```

Then, this session id he needs to send to a player who he wants to compete.
And then second player inputs sessionId and gets a task description.

```
@GetMapping("/connect")
    public Task connect(@RequestParam("sessionId") String sessionId) throws InterruptedException {

        Session session = sessionService.findOne(sessionId);

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
        User playerSecond = userService.findOne(currentPrincipalName);
        session.setPlayerSecond(playerSecond);
        sessionService.save(session);
        return session.getTask();
    }
```

I wonder how to make the rest endpoint to wait until both players with same sessionId calls it and then notify them with the task description.

I want them to write code within a one session, with a one code timer.
Please suggest how I should do that

Comment: Have you considered notifying the first player by means of `WebSocket`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be achieve like this

You could use a DeferredResult result and store it in a map until a user with the same sessionId joins. Ex

```
Map<String, DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>>> unconnected = new HashMap<String, DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>>>();
```

User one would call the connect `prepareSessionAPI` to receive the sessionId

User one would then call the connect API. The connet api would store this request/defferred result in the hashmap until user 2 joins. Ex

```
DeferredResult<Task> unconnectedTask = new DeferredResult<Task>();
unconnected.put(sessionId, unconnectedTask);
```

Now, user one's request would be stored in an in memory map until user two joins

User one would send the sessionId to user two

User two would call the `connect` API. The connect API would look for the session in the `HashMap`, and if it exists, it would perform the operations needed, then set the result of the deferred result. Ex

```
DeferredResult<Task> unconnectedTask = unconnected.get(sessionId);

if(unconnectedTask != null) {
    // Do work
    unconnectedTask.setResult(task);
} else {
  // This is user one's request
}
```

Please note, this is pseudo code.

Answer (score -1):

put this code both of method,
please import spring transnational jar

```
 @Transactional(propagation =Propagation.REQUIRED,isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE,readOnly=false,transactionManager="transactionManager")
```

if any issue inform